# React-BoilerPlate deploy to heroku successful but Application Error

Tags: heroku, react-boilerplate

i clone React-BoilerPlate and edit for test create web 
and i try deploy to heroku 
it's successful in log  but when i open browser it show "Application Error"
(in my mac dont have problem it working)

logs in dashboard.heroku.com

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=5
       engines.npm (package.json):   >=3

       Resolving node version >=5...
       Downloading and installing node 10.4.1...
       Bootstrapping npm >=3 (replacing 6.1.0)...
       npm 6.1.0 installed
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > myapp@1.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm run npmcheckversion


       > myapp@1.0.0 npmcheckversion /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js


       > myapp@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm run build:dll


       > myapp@1.0.0 build:dll /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js

       audited 25883 packages in 17.902s
       found 46 vulnerabilities (8 low, 38 moderate)
       run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > myapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm install && npm run build


       > myapp@1.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm run npmcheckversion


       > myapp@1.0.0 npmcheckversion /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js


       > myapp@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm run build:dll


       > myapp@1.0.0 build:dll /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js

       audited 25883 packages in 16.989s
       found 46 vulnerabilities (8 low, 38 moderate)
       run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

       > myapp@1.0.0 prebuild /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > npm run build:clean


       > myapp@1.0.0 build:clean /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > rimraf ./build


       > myapp@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18
       > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout

       Hash: d1b0ba3fc6910d2a897a
       Version: webpack 3.5.5
       Time: 45827ms
       Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       68b0c4fcb84d239f261c1a5e65818142.gif    4.13 kB          [emitted]
       bc47c23f4a28a80f48dbafb4ae48d853.svg  602 bytes          [emitted]
       b812ddd6e7e7c9bd9fc5ba89d1a87ecd.svg  693 bytes          [emitted]
       68d2042ac5fdae4387e8f3b98e80d755.png    19.3 kB          [emitted]
       0ae4b3198c60ae8e849a17c2b9e36362.png    1.99 kB          [emitted]
       0c41c45073224f7bf4dfdbf7b703c05c.png    2.34 kB          [emitted]
       ec6994795fdd10b1a14a82dd076e7c31.otf    40.1 kB          [emitted]
       ce0b1f00d0b40ef65010ac4ec7e4f6a3.otf    39.8 kB          [emitted]
       .htaccess.bin    1.79 kB          [emitted]
       favicon.ico     370 kB          [emitted]
       icon-120x120.png    11.2 kB          [emitted]
       icon-128x128.png    11.2 kB          [emitted]
       icon-144x144.png    12.7 kB          [emitted]
       icon-152x152.png    13.9 kB          [emitted]
       icon-167x167.png    16.5 kB          [emitted]
       icon-180x180.png    14.4 kB          [emitted]
       icon-192x192.png    17.9 kB          [emitted]
       icon-384x384.png      42 kB          [emitted]
       icon-512x512.png    16.7 kB          [emitted]
       icon-72x72.png    5.89 kB          [emitted]
       icon-96x96.png    8.11 kB          [emitted]
       manifest.json  975 bytes          [emitted]
       9a4cbc132ce42296701bb3cc91fc8bd3.svg  930 bytes          [emitted]
       ced611daf7709cc778da928fec876475.eot    2.05 kB          [emitted]
       f97e3bbf73254b0112091d0192f17aec.svg    2.15 kB          [emitted]
       d41f55a78e6f49a5512878df1737e58a.ttf    1.89 kB          [emitted]
       b7c9e1e479de3b53f1e4e30ebac2403a.woff    1.38 kB          [emitted]
       0.0f8f8d839c3c67ea9a03.chunk.js     343 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]
       1.d9aef47ea860a023a399.chunk.js     331 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]
       2.02140dd8fb729e8ec62d.chunk.js     338 kB       2  [emitted]  [big]
       3.59f24490e8d9db438d4a.chunk.js     162 kB       3  [emitted]
       4.dedc780d9ee602a24732.chunk.js    81.5 kB       4  [emitted]
       5.14ce9b3d76aef2ba3592.chunk.js    40.6 kB       5  [emitted]
       6.0c6db533aceba6385e37.chunk.js    45.3 kB       6  [emitted]
       7.98b59f40657a56912eaf.chunk.js      46 kB       7  [emitted]
       8.3a4ea6143fc6f0ca179e.chunk.js    26.1 kB       8  [emitted]
       9.13d365030651a79eb21d.chunk.js    17.5 kB       9  [emitted]
       10.1e3ab2bf211e3c6c6232.chunk.js    41.1 kB      10  [emitted]
       11.260090743f2cac2a0f93.chunk.js    24.1 kB      11  [emitted]
       12.7bcdf07c7edc3ce0a11d.chunk.js    24.4 kB      12  [emitted]
       13.c4e98897ef480410016d.chunk.js  716 bytes      13  [emitted]
       main.898cbfbcec44f3cfa4c2.js    1.25 MB      14  [emitted]         main
       index.html    1.06 kB          [emitted]
       sw.js    20.6 kB          [emitted]

       WARNING in ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js
       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in '/tmp/build_4cc58fca63d336e918330c92a7320a18/node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale'
       @ ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js 56:12-46
       @ ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locale.js
       @ ./node_modules/moment/src/moment.js
       @ ./app/components/home/cover/calendar/index.js
       @ ./app/components/home/cover/index.js
       @ ./app/components/home/index.js
       @ ./app/containers/HomePage/index.js
       @ ./app/containers/HomePage/Loadable.js
       @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
       @ ./app/app.js
       @ multi ./app/app.js
       Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
       1 asset
       Child __offline_serviceworker:
       1 asset
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies

       > pre-commit@1.2.2 uninstall node_modules/pre-commit
       > node uninstall.js

       removed 1620 packages and audited 1114 packages in 19.282s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 38.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v12
       https://myapp-pr-4.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

logs by code `heroku logs --tail --app myapp`

```
2018-06-19T08:33:45.641928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2018-06-19T08:33:45.641928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-06-19T08:33:46.752542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-06-19T08:33:46.917240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

(i have logs 2018-06-19T08:01:33.875099+00:00 app[web.1] but just '___' is defined but never used)

and in browser myapp show like that
(photo in link)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMjMi.png)

thank you for your help
if u need more detail , tell me i will show u

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and following react-boilerplate instructions made it work for me. Here is the link: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/general/deployment.md

What it says:

Heroku
Easy 5-Step Deployment Process
Step 1: Create a Procfile with the following line: `web: npm run start:prod.` We do this because Heroku runs npm run start by default, so we need this setting to override the default run command.

Step 2: Install the Node.js buildpack for your Heroku app by running the following command: `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v91 -a [your app name].` Make sure to replace #v91 with whatever the latest buildpack is, which you can find here. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/releases.

Step 3: Add this line to your package.json file in the scripts area: `"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",`. This is so Heroku can build your production assets when deploying (more of which you can read about here). Then, adjust the prebuild script in your package.json file so it looks like this: `"prebuild": "npm run build:clean",` to avoid having Heroku attempt to run Jest tests (which are unsupported with this buildpack).

Step 4: Run `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` so that Heroku can compile the NPM modules included in your devDependencies (since many of these packages are required for the build process).

Step 5: Follow the standard Heroku deploy process:

`git add .
git commit -m 'Made some epic changes as per usual'
git push heroku master`